# How do I show this set collection is a topology basis?

Tags: general-topology

For any point $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z^{2}}$ we define $B_{(m,n)} := B_{m} × B_{n}$, where $B_{n}$ holds the basis elements for the digital line. That means $B_{n}=\{n\}$ if n is odd, and $B_{n}=\{n-1, n, n+1\}$ when n is even.
I have to show $B =  \{B_{(m,n)}
: m, n ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$ is in fact a basis for a topology in $\mathbb{Z^{2}}$ (digital plane topology).
I'm unsure how to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition in Munkres' Sec. 13, let $m \times n \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Without loss of generality, there are three cases according as either, both, or neither of $m$ and $n$ is odd.

Case 1: If $m$ and $n$ both are odd, then $m \times n \in \{m\} \times \{n\}$, and 
$$\{m\} \times \{n\} = B_m \times B_n = B_{(m, n)}. $$

Case 2: If $m$ and $n$ both are even, then $m \times n \in \{m-1, m, m+1\} \times \{n-1, n, n+1\}$, and 
$$\{m-1, m, m+1\} \times \{n-1, n, n+1\}= B_m \times B_n = B_{(m, n)}. $$

Case 3: If, say, $m$ is odd and $n$ is even, then $m \times n \in \{m \} \times \{n-1, n, n+1\}$, and 
$$\{ m \} \times \{n-1, n, n+1\}= B_m \times B_n = B_{(m, n)}. $$

Thus for every element in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ there is a set in our proposed basis containint that element.

Now let $B_{(m, n)}$ and $B_{(p, q)}$ be any two sets in our proposed basis, where $m, n, p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, and let $a \times b \in B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)}$. We need a basis set $B_{(r, s)}$ such that 
$$ a \times b \in B_{(r, s)} \subset B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)}. $$

Now there are $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 16$ distinct cases according to whether all, some, or none of $m, n, p, q$ are odd.

Here we discuss only a couple of these cases.

If $m, n, p, q$ all are odd, then $B_m = \{m\}$, $B_n = \{n\}$, $B_p = \{ p \}$, $B_q = \{ q\}$, and since 
$$ a \times b \in B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)} = \left( B_m \times B_n \right) \cap \left( B_p \times B_q \right) = \left( B_m \cap B_p \right) \times \left( B_n \cap B_q \right), $$
therefore we must have $$ a = m = p \ \mbox{ and } b = n = q. $$
And so 
$$ a \times b \in \{a\}\times \{b\} = B_a \times B_b =  B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)}, $$
and $B_a \times B_b$ is a set in our proposed basis.

If $m$ and $q$ are odd and $n$ and $p$ are even, then $B_m = \{ m \}$, $B_n = \{n-1, n, n+1\}$, $B_p = \{p-1, p, p+1 \}$, and $B_q = \{ q \}$, and so 
$$ B_{(m, n)} = \{ m \} \times \{ n-1, n, n+1 \} \ \mbox{ and } \ B_{(p, q)} = \{ p-1, p, p+1 \} \times \{q\}, $$
which implies that 
$$ a = m = p\pm 1 \ \mbox{ and } \ b = q = n \pm 1. $$
And so 
$$ a \times b \in \{ m \} \times \{ q \} =  B_{(m, q)} \subset B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)}. $$

If $m, n, p, q$ are all even, then we have $B_m = \{ m-1, m, m+1 \}$, $B_n = \{ n-1, n, n+1 \}$, $B_p = \{ p-1, p, p+1\}$, and $B_q = \{ q-1, q, q+1\}$. Now there are three sub-cases according as either, both or neither of $a$ and $b$ is odd.

If both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then we must have 
$$ a = m \pm 1, \ a = p \pm 1, \ \mbox{ and } \ b = n \pm 1, \ b = q \pm 1. $$
In this case 
$$ a \times b = \{ a \} \times \{ b \} = B_{(a, b)} \subset B_{(m, n)} \cap B_{(p, q)}. $$

If $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then we must have 
$$ a = m \pm 1, \ a = p \pm 1, \ \mbox{ and } \ b = n = q. $$
In this case
$$ a \times b \in \{ a \} \times \{ b-1, b, b+1 \} = B_{(a, b)} \subset B_{(m, n)} \times B_{(p, q)}. $$

The sub-case corresponding to both $a$ and $b$ being even is even easier.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: The specific topology is a red herring. It's a general fact, most easily shown in greater generality.

Comment: thank you very much! im trying to explore now the rest of possible cases

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the digital topology but holds generally:

> If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for some topology on $X$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ is some base for a topology on $Y$, then $$\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}':= \{O \times O': O \in \mathcal{B}, O' \in \mathcal{B}'\}$$
>
> is a base for some topology on $X \times Y$ (and it's called the product topology).

To check the two standard requirements:

It's clear that if $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ implies $x \in Y$ so $x \in B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ for some $B_x$ and likewise $y \in B_y \in \mathcal{B}'$ as well and then $(x,y) \in B_x \times B_y \in \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}'$ so the collection covers $X \times Y$.

Also, if $B_1 \times B_2, B_1' \times B_2' \in \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}'$ and $(x,y) \in (B_1 \times B_2) \cap (B'_1 \times B'_2)$, note that $x \in B_1 \cap B_1'$ so that there is some $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that

$$x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B'_1$$

and also there is some $B'_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that

$$y \in B_3 \subseteq B_2 \cap B'_2$$

But then

$$(x,y) \in B_3 \times B'_3 (\in \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}') \subseteq (B_1 \cap B'_1) \times (B_2 \cap B_2') = (B_1 \times B_2) \cap (B'_1 \times B'_2)$$

which shows the second condition for a base to be also fulfilled.